# java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: android, xml, layout

I must be staring at the problem and can't see it, so any help is appreciated.

I have a button declaration in my XML:

```
<Button xmlns:android="http//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/key_bg"
        android:text="Q" />
```

When the XML is inflated, I'm getting the above error and the app crashes.

I know for sure that it is this button that's causing the problem, because (1) the line number indicated in the error is exactly the line where this button is declare; and (2) I have several of these in the XML and if I comment out this one, I get the same error with line number pointing to the next button with the same declaration.

As far as I can see, `layout_width` and `layout_height` are there, so what is it complaining about?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi Aleks,just remove `xmlns:android="http//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` line from all controls apart from layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You lost ':' in xmlns:android = "http//....", try

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/key_bg"
    android:text="Q" />
```

Comment: Damn! I could be staring at this for years and not look twice at the `xmlns:android`.  Thanks a lot!